# How to install plugins in vim using vundle?

Tags: vim, plugins, macvim, youcompleteme

I am using Vundle to install YouCompleteMe (YCM).  However, I am unable to install it (the installation guide just says running `:PluginInstall`, but not what to do once the following page opens):

[image]

I tried hitting buttons like `return`, etc. but they don't seem to work.  Any guidance please?

Edit:  Also, note that at this point, it is not already installed because I am unable to see the `YouCompleteMe` directory in `bundle` (whereas it should be there).

`.vim` -> `bundle` -> `YouCompleteMe`

Edit:

My `.vimrc` looks like follows:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: how does your vimrc looks like (only the relevant part)

Comment: @snap, included it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running`PluginInstall` is a part of it. However, Vundle knows what plugins to install based on your .vimrc file.

Add another `Plugin` statement after the Vundle one, pointing to the plugin you want installed. If the plugin is on GitHub, this is as simple as using the repository name. So

```
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
```

Should help with your current issue. You may still need to compile the plugin and whatnot. See the [full installation guide](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#full-installation-guide) for full guidance on this topic.

Finally, you must ensure that `clang` is installed and run the compilation script.

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py --clang-completer
```

For this you'll need certain python headers and `cmake`, both of which may be found in the plugin installation guide linked above.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: After including `Valloric/YouCompleteMe`, it is showing processing since a long time.  Do you have an idea how long it'll take?

Comment: I've never used `YouCompleteMe`, but it says it has a compiled component. I think Vundle has a way to call that compilation, so I suspect it is processing for a long time because you are compiling the entire plugin. As far as I know this is normal.

Comment: Yes, but it gives an error `YcmServerShutdown`.  I am not sure how to overcome this?

Comment: Ok, I've got it. The last step is to compile the `ycm_core`. I've appended to the answer above,  but first check `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe` to see if the plugin has been downloaded.

Comment: It has been downloaded now, but I get the error `YcmServerShutdown`.  Restarting the server does not help! :(

Comment: Would you mind answer my new question as well, please: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47957625/8534521?

Answer (score 4):

Quick Guide For Vundle packages installation - **In short**:

1. Open terminal and edit the vimrc file (using `vim ~/.vimrc`)
2. paste the name of package according to the documentation, paste it between
   *vundle#begin()* and *vundle#end*.

> ```
> call vundle#begin()
> Plugin 'PluginAuthor/PluginName'
> call vundle#end()
> ```

for example:

```
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'dracula/vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

call vundle#end()
```

3. open Terminal and open vim (just `vim` ) and Type `:VundleInstall` 
   , On packages installation window, Wait until Vundle installer is getting finished.