# Why does my YCM Server shut down?

Tags: vim, plugins, vi, macvim, youcompleteme

Whenever I open vim, I get the message that Ycm Server has shutdown with exit code -6.  The log files contain the following info:

```
2017-12-23 21:25:50,550 - ERROR - Unable to connect to server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 217, in HandleServerException
    yield
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 237, in CheckIfServerIsReady
    'ready' )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 68, in GetDataFromHandler
    timeout ) )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 183, in JsonFromFuture
    response = future.result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 404, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54499): Max retries exceeded with url: /ready (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10b7cbd50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
2017-12-23 21:25:50,655 - ERROR - The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected exit code -6. Type ':YcmToggleLogs ycmd_54499_stderr_MqYNI6.log' to check the logs.
2017-12-23 21:26:05,494 - ERROR - Unable to connect to server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 217, in HandleServerException
    yield
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/shutdown_request.py", line 37, in Start
    self.PostDataToHandler( {}, 'shutdown', TIMEOUT_SECONDS )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 78, in PostDataToHandler
    timeout ) )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 183, in JsonFromFuture
    response = future.result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 404, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54499): Max retries exceeded with url: /shutdown (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10b80d2d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
2017-12-23 21:26:05,618 - ERROR - Unable to connect to server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 217, in HandleServerException
    yield
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 237, in CheckIfServerIsReady
    'ready' )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 68, in GetDataFromHandler
    timeout ) )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 183, in JsonFromFuture
    response = future.result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 404, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54502): Max retries exceeded with url: /ready (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10b80d650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
2017-12-23 21:26:05,721 - ERROR - The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected exit code -6. Type ':YcmToggleLogs ycmd_54502_stderr_fNX8sk.log' to check the logs.
2017-12-23 21:26:14,523 - ERROR - Unable to connect to server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 217, in HandleServerException
    yield
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/debug_info_request.py", line 41, in Start
    self._response = self.PostDataToHandler( request_data, 'debug_info' )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 78, in PostDataToHandler
    timeout ) )
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 183, in JsonFromFuture
    response = future.result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 404, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Users/abhisheknaik/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/pythonfutures/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 356, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54502): Max retries exceeded with url: /debug_info (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10b80da10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
```

Could someone please point out why is the connection lost?  Running `YcmRestartServer` does not help as the server shuts down again.

**Would highly appreciate *any* help**.  Thanks!

Comment: Put `let g:ycm_server_keep_logfiles = 1
let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'debug'` in your .vimrc. Use `:YcmDebugInfo` to see where the logs are kept, and read them. Post the output if the solution isn't obvious.

Comment: @Qwertycrackers, that's what I have done above.  I got the log details (posted above) after following the exact steps that you mention.

Comment: Whoops, didn't read as closely as I should. I can't find this exact error anywhere, but I can't help but suspect it might stem from not having the proper `libclang` available to the ycmd server. Can you check if the one you are using (probably system) has version greater than 3.2?

Comment: It also looks like [this](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2758) guy experienced a similar problem but there doesn't appear to be more info.

Comment: @Qwertycrackers, doing a `clang --version` gives: `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`; so I guess I am good with the version.

Comment: @Qwertycrackers, yeah, that's right; but not much info is provided about it.  And I am badly stuck. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161882/discussion-between-qwertycrackers-and-user6490375).

Comment: Use [one of the official YCM support channels](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#contact).

Comment: @romainl, thank you.  I'll post the question there as well.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I am getting the same type of error (Max retries exceeded with url: /debug_info)

Comment: @EtiennePellegrini, sorry for the late answer.  I never did. :(  I am not sure, but I guess the issue is that I was trying on MacOS High Sierra and it had not yet been enhanced for it.  But this is just my speculation - I am not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating YouCompleteMe. If using vim-plug:

```
:PlugUpdate YouCompleteMe
```

It worked for me.